# Why is my normal baking ending up with lowpoly normals?

Tags: normals, baking

Blender 2.9. I'm following a tutorial on character creation and modelling. I am modelling an orc. So far, it looks great -- except I'm struggling to get my normals to bake correctly from a  highpoly model to a lowpoly one.

Here's my lowpoly orc, with normals on it:
[image]

Here's my normal map:
[image]

Here's the highpoly version:
[image]

And here are my baking settings:
[image]

I've tried all manner of ray length settings, extrusion and have even tried a cage with a blown up orc. The steps I've been following are (1) select Cycles renderer. (2) hold ctrl (3) select the highpoly orc. (4) select the lowpoly orc. (5) select the normal map in the nodes window. (6) hit "Bake".

As you can see, my process worked for all the other objects (like the horns, teeth, shackle, belt, etc.) but not the orc!

Comment: Don't do 2.  Do 3 as a normal select, but do 4 while holding the shift key.

Comment: wow, amazingly, that worked! Can't say this is intuitive, lol. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're selecting the two objects.

- Do your step 1.
- Do not do your step 2.
- Do step 3 in the usual way for selecting an object, by left clicking on it.
- Do step 4 by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while left clicking on it.
- Do step 5
- Do step 6